# AIR - Open files on Android (openWithDefaultApplication() alternative)

Tags: android, api, air

I'm currently trying to open a downloaded file (.txt e.g.) on Android (2.2) programmatically through Adobe's AIR SDK.

On **desktop** AIR applications there is an API called `File.openWithDefaultApplication();`, which works fine.

Unfortunately this call doesn't work on Android based devices.

Do you guys know an alternative function to manage this - or point me in the right direction?

I guess it couldn't be that hard, but the relating information is quiet rare on Adobe's Knowledge Base ;-)

Thanx in advance.

Regards,
/dley

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening a file in another application is not supported, except for files that can be launched with http/s, mailto, sms, tel, and market URI schemes. You can launch those with the navigateToURL() function.

Of course, it isn't hard to display text inside an AIR app, if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: thank you for your response. The .txt example was quiet bad, it isn't about displaying text inside an AIR application. But your hint about `navigateToURL()` was very useful and it seems to work.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm kind of trying the same thing, with opening a pdf file. Could you explain how you opened the file? Especially from which directory. I tried opening it from `File.applicationDirectory` and `File.documentsDirectory`, doesn't work for me. neither with `openWithDefaultApplication` nor with `navigateToUrl`. I'd really appreciate the help.