# PDF in a Flex mobile application

Tags: apache-flex, pdf, flex4.5, flex-mobile

Is it possible to open a pdf file in a Flex Mobile application?
I have searched but I didn't find anything.

Thank you

Comment: This maybe relevant [AIR - Open files on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298302/air-open-files-on-android-openwithdefaultapplication-alternative)

Comment: I try with navigateToURL() like in the post be it doesn't go on mobile project :(

Answer (score 1):

Use [Document Launcher Native Extension for Android](http://activeden.net/item/document-launcher-native-extension-for-android/2015733).  I tried and it works nice!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using the StageWebView:

http://blog.wookets.com/2011/05/flex-mobile-using-stagewebview-to-show.html

Comment: I try it before asking. It is said that it was tried on iOS but not Android. I did this in Android and it doesn't works. It shows 'Web page not available'

Comment: Ok I just test it on an iPhone 4 and it works fine. But now I want to that it works on Android!

Comment: I guess it's a limitation of the Android browser. When I browse to a PDF on an android phone it seems to download it and then open it in a PDF reader. Try using the web browser to look at your PDF on the Android phone and see if it can read it.

Comment: You could also try converting the PDF to HTML?