# File.applicationStorageDirectory does not work on ios

Tags: ios, actionscript-3

I tried to open a pdf file on my app . I use this code block;

```
var _myfilename = ConfigurationManager.LessonPath + "media/" + friendlyFileName;

var realFile:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(_myfilename);

var destination:File = File.documentsDirectory;

destination = destination.resolvePath(_myfilename);

realFile.copyTo(destination,true);

destination.openWithDefaultApplication();
```

When I try it on flash simulator it works but when I try it on ios device it does not work.

is there different code block to open pdf file on ios device?
thank you

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: I didnt get any error . It is acting like no any action and pdf file is not opened.

Comment: How are you placing the PDF into the applicationStorageDirectory?

Comment: I would also debug the actual paths and trace them to see if anything is coming null, or if everything is populated correctly.

Comment: I don't think "openWithDefaultApplication();" is supposed to work on mobile device.

Comment: what can I use instead of openWithDefaultApplication() on mobile device , especially for iPad?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** As suggested correctly, `openWithDefaultApplication()` will not work on mobile devices. Have a look at this thread: [AIR - Open files on Android (openWithDefaultApplication() alternative)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298302/air-open-files-on-android-openwithdefaultapplication-alternative)

Instead, you should try to use `navigateToUrl()` to open your PDF file after it has finished copying into the location, and hopefully you should be able to open it in the external browser (untested). I would still recommend that you use an event listener as below and wait for the file to be copied over first.

---

From whatever details you have provided, I think the problem might be that you are probably not waiting for the file to be copied before you open it. I am assuming everything is right with your code, and there are no nulls or errors.

You should try using [copyToAsync](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#copyToAsync()) to copy your file, and add an event listener of `Event.COMPLETE` to your `destination` file object.

Obviously, listen to the `IOError` event as well in case there is an error to copy the file.

Once the `COMPLETE` event is fired, try to open the file then.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I did everything you said but result did not change. Could it be relevant to iOS 8?

Comment: @user3115233 Sorry for the late response. I have updated my answer, please check and try and let me know if it works. Don't forget to vote and accept the answer if it works out! Thanks.